# Show that $\mathcal C_{\mathcal C}(\mathbb R)$ incomplete w.r.t. sup-norm

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $f\in\mathcal C(\mathbb R).$ Let $f\in\mathcal C_{\mathcal C}(\mathbb R)$ denotes the space of all cont. real valued functions on $\mathbb R$ having compact support. Show that it is incomplete w.r.t. sup-norm?

I tried to visualize the solution as follows: I have taken the Cauchy sequence as below:

[image]

I took it for I can see the internal distance between two functions $f_m,f_n$ are tending to zero at a point as $m,n$ are getting larger. However $f_n$ is tending nowhere as the left nonzero part of $f_n$ is tending to a vertical line and hence cannot converge to a function. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Ah, but the space $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ of bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. And $C_C(\mathbb{R})$ embeds isometrically into $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ so your example would demonstrate that $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is not complete either.

Comment: @JacobGross: OMG! So my above idea is wrong. But when I visualize why doesn't it turn out to be wrong???

Comment: @Jave, it's wrong because it's not a Cauchy sequence. For any $f_n$, you can always find an $m > n$ so that the top of $f_m$ hangs over a point $x$ with $f_n(x) < 1/2$. Thus it does not satisfy the definition of Cauchy for $\epsilon = 1/2$.

Comment: You can take a bell curve -like function, cut it off at $-n,n$ and draw segments to the x-axis in such a way that the sequence is Cauchy. It's good to do this because that way,you see what's going on. But, if you want a ready-made sequence, the one I always remember is $f_n(x) = \dfrac{1-(x/n)^2}{1+x^2}$  on $[-n.n]$ zero otherwise.